# coffeescript how i can instantiate attribute

Tags: arrays, class, coffeescript

```
class Foo
  list: []
foos = []
for i in [1..2]
  foos.push new Foo
foos[0].list.push "a"
foos[1].list.push "a"
console.log foos[0].list
console.log foos[1].list
```

This code output was:

```
["a", "a"]
["a", "a"]
```

But i don't understand why the output wasn't:

["a"]
["a"]

Seems foos[k].list is static parameter!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the `list` value is shared across all foo instances.

Does it make sense to you if you look at the generated JS?

```
Foo = (function() {
  function Foo() {}

  Foo.prototype.list = [];

  return Foo;

})();
```

If I understand you correctly perhaps this is a valid solution to your problem:

```
class Foo
  constructor: ->
    @list = []
```